# File writer is writing the string with no "Line breaks"

Tags: java

It is a simple "file writing program" that scans a text file from the given directory and stores its content into a string initialized as " words" . Now, when the content is concatenated into the string. The spaces and the line breaks are preserved. However, when I attempt to write that string words into a file. The spaces are preserved but the lines breaks are lost. 
For example: 
Original String:
Hello. I am stuck in UMT.
Get me out of here.
File Writing: 
Hello, I am stuck in UMT. Get me out of here.
Notice the new line is not preserved? No line break? No " \n" ?

```
package testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Reader{ {

String words="this is a a new file created by me :D \n";
File file = new File("C:/file.txt");

  try {        
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(file);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        words= words.concat(scan.nextLine() + "\r ");
        } 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
ex);
    }

System.out.println(words);

try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/newfile.txt");
    writer.write(words);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


}}
```

Comment: `nextLine()` does not include the line-break and `\r` isn't one, `\n` is one. You are reading without breaks and writing without breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
words= words.concat(scan.nextLine() + "\r\n" );
```

The `nextLine()` scans each line without the line break. So you have to manually insert one.
Also, on Linux and MacOS machines, next line is `\n` but on most Windows machines, next line is `\r\n`.

Comment: @LegoGames don't do it like this, it makes your program only work on Windows. Either create a list of lines from the input and then use `println`, or do something like `words = words.concat(String.format ("%s%n", scan.nextLine()))`.

Answer (score 1):

\r is carriage return, \n is new line but as a general rule you have to look at the encoding type of your file because the new line character can differ from one encoding to another one.

[CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), LF, and CRLF are all commonly used end-of-line characters. In the world of PCs, CRLF is common amongst Windows apps, CR is common on the [Classic Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS), and LF is common on the modern [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) and Unix-oriented OSes ([BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution), [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), etc). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

#### Some more info

if you are facing some of these problems you have to keep in mind that different charecter encodings could have different notation for the new line. For example Word may use UTF-8 and Notepad may use ISO-8859-1 and you default system is setted on another type of encoding and it's not sure that every of this encoding share the same new line character. When you use the \n character you are typing the new line of your system so let's say you are working on windows this can display a new line that you can see in Word, but if you will open the same file on a Mac text editor you can see no new lines if they use different character encodings.

Comment: Both the files are txd. String "words" is able to store the text from the txt file with everything preserved. However, when I write the string into a new txd file (Notepad: Windows). spaces are preserved but the line breaks are lost. The lines just start after the ending sentence and never proceed to a new line.

Comment: JFYI `System.lineSeparator()` gives the correct separator for the current system.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also figured out \r\n worked too. Thanks man

Comment: you are welcom, just edited my answer for more info